# How can I refresh the data on my access Front End?

Tags: vba, ms-access, sharepoint, listbox

I built an access Form frontend with a sharepoint list called "teammates" as the back end.

The form is simple, consists of two listboxes that lists all teammates, one box is for absent teammates, the other is for present teammates. I have some buttons and methods that allow to update a teammates status, thus moving them into either the "absent" list box or the "present" box.

I also have a "Refresh" button on the page.

```
    Private Sub btnRefreshForm_Click()
        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdRefreshSharePointList
        CurrentDb.TableDefs("teammates").RefreshLink
        Me.lsbAbsentTeammates.Requery
        Me.lsbPresentTeammates.Requery
        Me.Requery
        Me.Refresh
    End Sub
```

My issue is this, when I share the FrontEnd with someone else, that person will send some teammates to the absent box, but I cannot see those changes, the Refresh button does not requery the data.

The only way I can see the updated data is if I close the front end and reopen it.

How can I see the updated data without having to close and reopen the application ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Refresh Sharepoint-linked Table in Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671241/refresh-sharepoint-linked-table-in-access)

Comment: I saw that post as well, I did not try it since the solution relies on using Windows Powershell. I want the "Refresh Data" button on the form to refresh the data .

Comment: Did you review the second answer to that question?

Comment: Yes I did, that did not work either.